# Enqueue scripts based on site.

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I have a wordpress multi-site implementation. I am a developing a custom plugin for this implementation.
Is it possible to include a script based based on the site.
if site is mydomain.com/uk :- script_uk.js need to be loaded
if site is mydomain.com/us : - script_us.js need to be loaded.

Comment: you can use this function to know the identifier of the actual site : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple Javascript/jQuery's function to check the url and enqueue the relevant js/css files?
You may use the below js line to achieve your task:

```
if(window.location.href == 'YOUR_DESIRED_URL') {
   // ENQUEUE JS 1
}
```

If you want to use php's function, you may also do that.